# Xcode 4: Unknown type name 'NSUInteger'; did you mean 'NSUInteger'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm stuck with my project.
I've defined a property with a NSUInteger type, like:

```
@property NSUInteger maxDepth
```

It doesn't matter if I make it an (assign) property or not, Xcode keeps on asking me

```
Unknown type name 'NSUInteger'; did you mean 'NSUInteger'?
```

I can't build, and it doesn't matter where or how I define a NSUInteger property, I just keep getting this error.
My project uses the LLVM 3.0 compiler and ARC, So switching to GCC4.2 is no option for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that somehow my project's prefix was corrupted. I've fixed it after noticing that the same errors were in a new project that imported my current code. Thanks for the help anyways. I'll keep my eyes closer on that prefix file...

Comment: How did you fix the corrupt prefix file? I have the same issue but don't know exactly what's corrupt about it

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with a new project.

There was some problem with Xcode 4.2.

I tried to changed the Compiler to the GCC4.2 and then changed it back to LLVM 3.0 after that it was bold (I believe there is still a bug to set it up correctly). After That I clean the project and rebuild and it worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... I'll get back to you with my solution, if I ever find one..